# Xcode is complaining that I don't have an icon for iPod Touch

Tags: ios, xcode

It says that my icon dimensions are 0x0 but when I check the file, it's 57x57.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your iTunes Connect, go to "Manage Your Apps", look for Download Application Loader at the bottom [or this link](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_2.5.1.dmg), not sure the link would work. There is a bug in shipped Application Loader that comes with XCode, after you install this Application Loader, it should be fine.

Comment: I get a message telling me the following "This version of Application Loader is incompatible with your version of OS X. Install the latest version of Xcode or download Application Loader from iTunes Connect. (1245)"